# An Exception Received Causes The Angular Code To Quit The Loop

Tags: angular, exception, rxjs

I have a code that stops running once the server is quitting since there is an exception which is not handled . I wish to add 2 things to the code and I am just not sure where is the correct place to add them .

1. Add the exception error handling to capture the error and display
2. Make sure the loop of http client posts will continue to work after the exception

   Below is the code and I would be very thankful for your help since I quit new in this

   ```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { delay, tap, mergeMap, repeat, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject<void>(); // Subject for unsubscribing
      public  curState;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      display = response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.curState=response;
      };

      poll = of({}).pipe(
        mergeMap(_ => this.pollOmni()),
        tap(this.display),
        delay(200),
        repeat(),
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      );

      pollOmni() {
        return this.http.post<any>('http://127.0.0.1:8084/api', { call: 'getInfo' });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.poll.subscribe();

      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next(); // Emit value to unsubscribe from ongoing subscriptions
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete(); // Complete the subject
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: you're looking for the `catchError()` operator !

Comment: thanks ,do you maybe know were in the code I should add it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use catchError with pipe inside the mergeMap(). Please find the more details about RxJs operators [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap)

```
poll = of({}).pipe(
 mergeMap((_) =>
  this.pollOmni().pipe(
    map((response) => response),
    catchError((error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
      return of({ error: error.response });
    })
  )
 ),
 tap(this.display),
 delay(200),
 repeat(),
 takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
);
```

Comment: Thanks  ,  I tried the above but it did not compile so I made it a bit diffrent and unfortunally the catch is not capturing and the application stopped . Do you maybe know what is the issue here :  poll = of({}).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => this.pollOmni()),catchError(err => {
      console.log("error captured");throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err; 
    }),
    tap(this.display),
    delay(200),
    repeat(),
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe), // Unsubscribe when ngUnsubscribe emits
  );

Comment: I've updated the code Please get the above code and try it out its working and tested

Answer (score 0):

You can use `catchError`

```
 errorHandler = (error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return throwError(error); 
  };

  poll = of({}).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => this.pollOmni().pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))),
    tap(this.display),
    delay(200),
    repeat(),
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  );
```